# Bash `if $variable; then` returns `0: command not found`

Tags: bash

My code is

```
[[ <some test I will need to verify several times> ]]
IS_WHAT_I_WANT=$?

if $IS_WHAT_I_WANT; then
  echo "Good"
fi
```

I've seen several examples of testing variables that store results of tests, so I was sure this would work. However, when I run this thing, I receive:

`-bash: 0: command not found`

Which seems that it's trying to run what's inside of `IS_WHAT_I_WANT` var, instead of simply testing it. Why is that? Why other examples of `if $var;` work and this one doesn't?

Running GNU bash 3.2.57

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is your expected output?

Comment: if runs a *command*. `0` is not a valid command. So, you can run `if grep -e foo bar; then ...`, which runs the command `grep`, or `if [ "$foo" = 0 ]`, which runs the command `[` (also called `test`).

Comment: ...if your shell is bash, you can also run `if (( foo == 0 ))`; the double-parens put you in a *math context*.

Comment: BTW, all-caps variable names are reserved -- your own variables should have names with at least one lower-case character. See relevant specification at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, fourth paragraph, keeping in mind that shell variables and environment variables share a namespace.

Comment: Thanks. But testing if something equals zero for truth value harms legibility. In almost every language I can assign something with a embedded logical value (for instance C, everything that's not zero has a true value, zero has a false value). So I can create a variable and test this variable

Comment: Why create a variable at all? Why not just `if your_command; then ...`, rather than `your_command; val=$?; if val-is-zero`(...)?

Comment: As for legibility, I suggest that you write your code -- in **any** language -- to be readable by people who actually are familiar with that language's idioms, rather than for readability by people who aren't. The most important reader, after all, is your future self -- and if you strive to learn the local idioms, your future self will grok them.

Comment: People who work in several different settings might be confused by bash's inverted logic, even if it is something deeply rooted in them.

Comment: You can store strings like `true` and `false` in your variables if you *really* want to run `if $varname` -- **but if you do that, people who understand the language will hate you, for good reason** (it's an idiom that leads to security bugs and inefficient code).

Comment: Yes, I know that. I don't disagree with you, the same piece of code has constructions of the type `test || failure will get you out of here`, that are common idioms of bash.

Comment: I think the best course of action here is to do `if <original_test>`, without assigning it to a variable. I ask you to add this thing to your answer. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for `if` takes a *command*; runs that command, and checks its exit status.

If you try to run `0` as a command, assuming you don't have a `/usr/bin/0` or similar, it'll fail -- thus resulting in a nonzero exit status.

Consider using a math context instead:

```
if (( IS_WHAT_I_WANT == 0 )); then
  : "do something here"
fi
```

---

Even better is not to store the exit status at all.

```
foo; foo_result=$?
if [ "$foo_result" = 0 ]; then
  : "something"
fi
```

...can generally be much more cleanly written as:

```
if foo; then
  : "something"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks. But testing if something equals zero for truth value harms legibility. In almost every language I can assign something with a embedded logical value (for instance C, everything that's not zero has a true value, zero has a false value). So I can create a variable and do `if should_i_say_hi printf "Hi";` That's legible. Writing `if [ $should_i_say_hi = 0 ]` is strange.

Comment: Writing `if [ $should_i_say_hi = 0 ]` is also buggy; it'll cause a syntax error rather than a test failure if `should_i_say_hi` is empty. Quotes are important.

Comment: It doesn't harm legibility in shell scripts, because testing against 0 is the idiomatic way of checking a command's exit value. Unlike with other languages, in a shell script this is the best way to write the test. If you want to avoid tests like this then avoid saving off the value of `$?`. Once you do, you're stuck with an ugly `==` comparison.

Answer (score 0):

The `if` command has very specific requirements.  You need square brackets and a test case.  In `bash`, run `help test` to learn more about what kind of expressions you can have between square brackets.  In this case, you just want to know if it's zero (which denotes a clean exit).

Here you go:

```
[[ <some test I will need to verify several times> ]]
IS_WHAT_I_WANT=$?

if [ $IS_WHAT_I_WANT = 0 ]; then
  echo "Good"
fi
```

From your comments disliking the three nearly identical answers posted here so far, you have noted that you do not want an extra evaluation.  You can do that like this:

```
if [[ <some test I will need to verify several times> ]]; then
  IS_WHAT_I_WANT=true
else
  IS_WHAT_I_WANT=false
fi

if $IS_WHAT_I_WANT; then
  echo "Good"
fi
```

This runs the builtins `true` and `false` instead of a shell expression.  It does the same thing.

Of course, if you don't need that return value later, you could just place the conditional up front:

```
if [[ <some test I will need to verify several times> ]]; then
  echo "Good"
fi
```

Comment: `[ $IS_WHAT_I_WANT = 0 ]` is a test that returns 0. Why can't I swap it for a 0 instead since I already know it?

Comment: You don't need to follow an if by a test. You can follow it by any command (and it will branch if the return value is zero)

Comment: In POSIX shell, commands return integers, representing either a clean exit (zero) or else an error code.  If `$IS_WHAT_I_WANT` is _not_ zero, the `echo` will never run.  `if` **must** be followed by a command.  `[` is a command you can use to evaluate a test.  The `if` command itself is incapable of performing its own evaluations, so you must give it a command of some sort.  `0` is not a command, so `if` spit out an error.

Answer (score 0):

The return code stored in the `IS_WHAT_I_WANT` isn't a boolean value. Try something like

```
if [[ $IS_WHAT_I_WANT == 0 ]]; then
   echo "Good"; 
fi
```

or shorter

```
[[ $IS_WHAT_I_WANT == 0 ]] && echo "Good"
```

Comment: It's not a "boolean value" in a strict sense, but it is a return value, that's what `if` looks at (`if /bin/true` for example is a valid command)

Comment: right, `true` is a command, but `$IS_WHAT_I_WANT` isn't a command. That's why you need to use the "test to zero command"

Answer (score 0):

In my case I didn't have spaces between the square braces and the condtions inside

So had:

```
if [[$IS_WHAT_I_WANT=0]]; then
   echo "Good"; 
fi
```

but should have been:

```
if [[ $IS_WHAT_I_WANT=0 ]]; then
   echo "Good"; 
fi
```